# How do I remove quotes/cartouches from document output on Isabelle?

Tags: isabelle, literate-programming

Consider this snippet:

```
  lemma no_lift:
    assumes ‹∀L . ⟦γ L⟧ ≠ set L›     ― ‹Miner \<^term>‹γ› is non-trivial.›
    defines ‹γ' P N ≡ γ P›           
    shows ‹∀P. ∃N. set N ∩ ⟦γ' P N⟧ ≠ {}›
```

When I generate latex or HTML output locally, the cartouches remain in the output. When I look at proof documents in the AFP, it seems the cartouches and quotes have been stripped.

How can I strip quotes and cartouches from document output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `\isabellestyle{it}` in `root.tex`